# Including QUADPACK as a module

Tags: fortran

I am trying to integrate [QUADPACK](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/quadpack_double/quadpack_double.html) in my Fortran 90 code. I tried calling the subroutines in my main file and that worked fine.

In order to not litter my main file I tried moving the integration part of the code into a module. However, when I wrote my module as

```
module integrate 

   use ...

   call dqage(params..)

contains 

   functions

end module
```

I get the following message

```
Unexpected CALL statement in MODULE at (1).
```

I understood from another post that it is against the standard of Fortran to make such calls from modules. Consequently, I tried enveloping the quadpack code into a module thinking that that would help. It did not as now I get the following error when compiling

```
/usr/bin/ld: quadpack_double.o: in function `__quadpack_MOD_dqc25s':
quadpack_double.f90:(.text+0xce29): undefined reference to `dqwgts_'
```

So, my question is how can I integrate QUADPACK such that I can use it in other places besides the main file?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a specific tag for the old Fortran 90 where it is relevant, but here it is not. When showing code, please show the actual code you are compiling [mcve].

Comment: Please show the exact code that produces the error message end the exact command you use for compiling. How are you linking the library?

Comment: The `CALL` statement is classified as an executable statement.  An executable statement cannot appear in the specification part of a `MODULE`, which is the portion  above `CONTAINS` statement.

Comment: @evets Thank you. It worked fine when I placed the `call` statement in a subroutine placed below the `contains` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile all quadpack files and link against them.

A module to interface the quadpack routines will make your programming life easier. The following module shows one way to do it

```pascal
module quadpack_m
  use, intrinsic :: ieee_arithmetic
  implicit none

  private
  public :: QUADPACK_ERROR, quadpack_int

  interface
    function quadpack_integrand(x) result(f)
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real             :: f
    end function
  end interface

  character(*), parameter :: QUADPACK_ERROR(6) = [ &
    "maximum number of subdivisions achieved",     &
    "roundoff error detected                ",     &
    "extremely bad integrand behaviour      ",     &
    "algorithm does not converge            ",     &
    "integral is probably divergent         ",     &
    "input is invalid                       "      &
  ]

  external :: dqags, dqagi

contains

  subroutine quadpack_int(f, a, b, atol, rtol, result, aerr, neval, ier, limit, last)
    procedure(quadpack_integrand)  :: f
      !! function to integrate
    real,              intent(in)  :: a
      !! lower integration limit
    real,              intent(in)  :: b
      !! upper integration limit
    real,              intent(in)  :: atol
      !! absolute tolerance
    real,              intent(in)  :: rtol
      !! relative tolerance
    real,              intent(out) :: result
      !! output result of integration
    real,    optional, intent(out) :: aerr
      !! optional: output estimate of the modulus of the absolute error, which should equal or exceed abs(i-result)
    integer, optional, intent(out) :: neval
      !! optional: output number of integrand evaluations
    integer, optional, intent(out) :: ier
      !! optional: output error code
    integer, optional, intent(in)  :: limit
      !! optional: maximum number of subintervals (default: 4096)
    integer, optional, intent(out) :: last
      !! optional, output number of subintervals used

    ! local variables
    integer              :: neval_, ier_, limit_, lenw, last_, inf
    integer, allocatable :: iwork(:)
    real                 :: aerr_, bnd
    real,    allocatable :: work(:)
    logical              :: a_inf, b_inf

    limit_ = 4096
    if (present(limit)) limit_ = limit
    lenw = limit_ * 4

    allocate (iwork(limit_), work(lenw))

    a_inf = (ieee_class(a) == IEEE_NEGATIVE_INF)
    b_inf = (ieee_class(b) == IEEE_POSITIVE_INF)

    bnd = 0
    if (a_inf .and. b_inf) then
      inf = 2
    elseif (a_inf) then
      bnd = b
      inf = -1
    elseif (b_inf) then
      bnd = a
      inf = +1
    else
      inf = 0
    end if

    if (inf == 0) then
      call dqags(f, a,   b,   atol, rtol, result, aerr_, neval_, ier_, limit_, lenw, last_, iwork, work)
    else
      call dqagi(f, bnd, inf, atol, rtol, result, aerr_, neval_, ier_, limit_, lenw, last_, iwork, work)
    end if

    if (present(aerr )) aerr  = aerr_
    if (present(neval)) neval = neval_
    if (present(ier  )) ier   = ier_
    if (present(last )) last  = last_
  end subroutine

end module
```

Note that this code assumes compilation by default 8-byte floats/ints, e.g. `$ ifort -i8 -real-size 64` or `$ gfortran -fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-real-8`.
If portability is an important issue one should not be using those compile options but rather be using `iso_fortran_env` to specify data types, i.e. `INT64, REAL64`.

Comment: If one needs to use `-fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-real-8` with some piece of code, then one should find better code.  These options (and similar for other compilers) are the absolute worse way to port code to a higher precision.

Comment: I agree with @evets in general. Nevertheless, the main point of the question was how to use quadpack in modern Fortran. I hope that the code shows how to achieve that.
If he needs portable code it still should give him a good starting point.

Comment: @evets I have appended to the answer a slight remark about portability.